# Postman Tests Console Log

Tags: javascript, postman

I'm trying to write up a console.log under Tests in Postman to do two things

1- Count how many types/Unique "ShipmentStatus" were received in the response body (In-Process,Shipped, & Rejected)

2 - How how many of each ShipmentStatus we received for example (4 Orders In-Process 5 Orders in Complete)

How can I accomplish 1 and 2 to show up in my console.log?

```
"Orders": [
    {
        "id": 544789,
        "Company": {
            "ClientName": "Therese",
        },
        "Shipping": {
            "Address": "Street,",
        },

        "userId": "1413260",
        "ShipmentStatus": "In-Process"
    },
    {
        "id": 544787,
        "Company": {
            "ClientName": "Therese",
        },
        "Shipping": {
            "Address": "Street,",
        },

        "userId": "1413260",
        "ShipmentStatus": "Shipped"
    },
            {
        "id": 544786,
        "Company": {
            "ClientName": "Therese",
        },
        "Shipping": {
            "Address": "Street,",
        },

        "userId": "1413260",
        "ShipmentStatus": "Rejected"
    },
```

I'm able to obtain the total records received by doing the following

```
 console.log("Total Orders : " + response.Orders.length);
```

Comment: What did you try so far? It doesn't have to be syntactic correct, even just a pseudo-code algorithm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do something very quick and dirty like this, if all you want to see is those values logged out to the Console:

```
console.log(`Total Orders: ${pm.response.json().Orders.length}`)

var counts = {};
for (var i = 0; i < pm.response.json().Orders.length; i++) {
    counts[pm.response.json().Orders[i].ShipmentStatus] = 1 + (counts[pm.response.json().Orders[i].ShipmentStatus] || 0);
}

console.log(counts)
```

I extended your JSON response so that you could see what it would look like if you had more items:

[image: Postman Console]

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using object:

```
    var buffer = {}
    var orders = pm.response.json().Orders;
    orders.forEach(function(item) {
      var id = item.ShipmentStatus;
    if(buffer[id]) buffer[id]++
      else buffer[id] = 1;
    })
    for(var status in buffer)
    {
    console.log(status + ":" +buffer[status])
    }
    console.log(Object.keys(buffer).length+" unique values")
```

So you understood me.